# Choppy CSS hover animation on <div> with multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to build a small interactive animation in CSS and I ran into the following problem:

The animation consists of a container div that contains two img and three button elements. If you hover over this div a small jQuery function fires, that adds multiple classes to the elements and thus triggers the CSS animations.
When the cursor leaves the div, those classes are removed and the animation is played backwards.

If the cursor enters the div and stays on one element, the animation runs ok, but as soon as the cursor hits multiple elements during the animation, it starts to get choppy. You can reproduce this by pulling your cursor across the image and the buttons in one swipe.

I know, the code is a bit hacky, but I'm learning. As far as I can tell, it *should* run smoothly this way, since none of the elements inside the div should react dircetly to the hover. Does anybody know, why it doesn't and what causes this?

You can find all the files including the images here: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ACKTaR-znDrMjkakD_p5l-4-5Tul-2_O)

```js
/*Fitnessstudio*/
$("#fit_container").mouseover(function() {
  $("#fit_container").addClass("geb_cont_anim");
  $("#fit_container").addClass("geb_cont_anim_z-index");
  $("#fit_img_grau").addClass("geb_img_anim");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("#fit_container").removeClass("geb_cont_anim");
  $("#fit_container").removeClass("geb_cont_anim_z-index");
  $("#fit_img_grau").removeClass("geb_img_anim");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3c3c3b;
}

.geb_container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.geb_img_farb, .geb_img_grau {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.geb_img_grau {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.geb_img_anim {
  opacity: 0;
}

.geb_cont_anim {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

#fit_dummy {
  padding-top: 110%;
}

#fit_container {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 30%;
}

/*trigger-buttons allgemein*/

button.button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 350;
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}

.button-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
  background-color: #aecb37;
  color: black;
  width: 2.5vw;
  height: 2.5vw;
  transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
}

.button-circle span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -16%;
  left: 17%;
}

.button-circle:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

/*trigger-buttons konkret*/

#button1 {
  top: 27%;
  left: 83%;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#button2 {
  margin-top: 58%;
  left: 83%;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#button3 {
  margin-top: 90%;
  left: 83%;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="geb_container" id="fit_container">
        <img src="img/fit_farb.png" class="geb_img_farb" id="fit_img_farb" alt="fit_farb">
        <img src="img/fit_grau.png" class="geb_img_grau" id="fit_img_grau" alt="fit_grau">
        <button id="button1" class="button fit_button" data-modal="modal1">
          <div class="button-circle"><span>+</span></div>
          </button>
        <button id="button2" class="button fit_button" data-modal="modal2">
          <div class="button-circle"><span>+</span></div>
          </button>
        <button id="button3" class="button fit_button" data-modal="modal3">
          <div class="button-circle"><span>+</span></div>
          </button>
        <div id="fit_dummy">
        </div>
      </div>
  <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you decribe your expectations a bit more clearly. What do you mean if the cursor hits more elements at the same time?

Comment: I tried the files from google drive and can't reproduce the problem you describe. Seems pretty smooth here (Windows, Chrome). 
Are you getting the same result on all platforms?

BTW, you can simplify matters (and possibly improve performance) by using a hover pseudo class on the container div css instead of manipulating the classes with jQuery.

You can select the children in the hover state with something like `#fit_container:hover >  #fit_img_grau`

Comment: There's a slight stuttering when hovering over the image and button at the same time. Read carefully, this is actually a very well written first question.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yes, the issue Joseph describes, is what I meant. @brennanyoung I've included a video on Google Drive that shows what I mean exactly.  It's like there's a small "gap" between the image and the buttons that causes those small lags. The issue occurs on all browsers I've tried. I'll try the pseudo class, maybe that fixes it. Nonetheless I'd like to know, what causes the stuttering, since I find it quite an odd thing to happen, because the only thing that should react to the cursor is the div, not the buttons or the image. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean. Well you have a :hover on the buttons, so they *are* set up to respond to the mouse. I suppose the transform effect gets briefly interrupted or slowed down by those extra hover effects. 

Redrawing the button in a new color from a font glyph is essentially vector graphics work, which is relatively 'expensive'.

You might get improved performance using a 'css sprite' for those: Moving background position of a bitmap is typically faster because the processor just has to copy a different bunch of pixels from the bitmap already loaded in memory.

Comment: FWIW I tried renaming the selector `.button-circle:hover`(disabling it), and the choppiness improved somewhat, but not entirely, although the color change was lost, of course. There is a default hover effect on buttons.
Could use lose the div and span inside the buttons? Maybe this nesting is enough to trip up the animation? Simplify using background image on the button itself?

Comment: I replaced all the jquery stuff with the :hover pseudo class on the #fit_container element, just like you recommended earlier and that did the job for me. It works without any noticeable interruption. I'll try the css sprite instead of the font glyph, too, if it's better for performance. Thank you very much for your help!